# Tracking visitors with random session identifier in PHP?

Tags: php, security

I have got an own CMS in PHP, and I log the fishy attempts in the database, eg.:
- requests for non exists URL-s
- not valid email address for login
- etc.

If someone is trying to hack my system, I would like to deny, but I have to identifi him/her/it.
- If the user is logged in, the identification is via USERNAME.
- IF NOT, but the user has got IP address, the identification is via IP ADDRESS.
- IF NOT, ... what can I do?

If the user is not logged in, and -has not a IP address, I am generating an unique random identifier, and storeing in a SESSION variable.

So, a function is collecting the fishy attempts to the database, and if someone has got a critical amount of attempt, I put the username/IP address/session identifier to the banned list.

For the ip address:

```
function getUserIP() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

And for the random ID generator is:

```
if (!isset ($_SESSION["short_lived_identifier"]))
{
   $_SESSION["short_lived_identifier"] = bin2hex (openssl_random_pseudo_bytes (32));
}
```

Is it a good solution?
Thanks!

Comment: how can a user not have an IP address ?

Comment: Some of those variables are often arrays.

Comment: you need to separate login attempts that are fishy from the random noise of bots ever sites gets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a great solution, and there's a few reasons why:

- **It won't catch bad guys:** Unless you've configured something special, sessions are typically stored in cookies on the client.  If a malicious person wants to keep assaulting your website, they just clear the cookies frequently.  Thus, this method probably won't detect a malicious user who knows what they're doing.
- **It really won't catch bad guys:** Someone who really knows what they're doing can easily access a lot of different IP addresses.  You can simulate that by [downloading Tor](https://www.torproject.org/index.html.en) and looking up your IP address on a few different sites.  You'll get different answers--probably from different parts of the world--each time.
- **It may block actual users:** If the IP blocking is based purely on some number of failed login attempts from a particular IP address, what happens when that IP address corresponds to many users and they make normal mistakes in their passwords?  For instance, in an office building, let's say you have 200 users all sharing an internet connection, and thus also all sharing an IP address.  If 20 of them mess up their passwords once (for a total of 20 failed logins on that IP), does that lock out all 200 users?
- **Content matters, too:** Malicious attempts are often (though, not always) marked by some sort of malicious content.  For instance, you may see an attempt at [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) in form fields.  It's easy enough to detect that sort of syntax and act appropriately.

A better solution, adopted by quite a lot of organizations around the world, is to track the number of attempts for a given username, and lock the account once there's too many attempts *for that username*.  Once locked, different applications use different approaches to unlock the account: some use a verification email, others just wait a set amount of time, others require that the user also complete a [captcha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) with each new login attempt... The goal is to *slow down* the bad guys, so that they can't just brute-force their way into a system.

You have not one, but two objectives in designing this sort of system: keep the bad guys (and their bots) out, and also minimize inconvenience to users.  Locking a building full of people out of an application may meet the first criteria, but it fails hard on the second.

There are times when it would be appropriate to block an whole IP forever (or, at least, forever-ish).  But if you want the application to not lock out users, blocking IPs isn't the best place to start.

Comment: Thank You.
I know, this is not a perfect solution to tracking all visitors, but better than nothing.

The login has got an own security function. It gives 10 min blocking after 5 unsuccessfull try.

I would like to scare away the malicious persons. Can the hacker found a portal with less security functions? Yes. Then go, and try with it!

Comment: Glad to help.  Thanks for accepting the answer.  I suppose the most important thing is to make sure you avoid locking out legitimate users without cause (the office building example), because you don't want to turn your legitimate, happy users into locked-out, disgruntled users.